# What does *|*:link target in css?

Tags: css

I've come across `*|*:link` under the PreferenceStyleSheet in Firefox, but what specifically does it target? I gather that `*:link` pseudo class would mean 'all visited urls', but what about the `*|` ?

Answer (score 2):

Universal selector
Selects all elements. Optionally, it may be restricted to a specific namespace or to all namespaces.
Syntax: * ns|* *|*
Example: * will match all the elements of the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors